# How to convert HHMMSS to HH:MM:SS Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I tried to convert the HHMMSS to HH:MM:SS and I am able to convert it successfully but my script takes 2 hours to complete because of the file size. Is there any better way (fastest way) to complete this task

```
Data File
data.txt

10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,071600,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,072200,072200,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TAB,072600,072600,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,073200,073200,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,073500,073500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,MRO,073700,073700,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,CPT,073900,073900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,074400,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,090200,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,090900,090900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,091500,091500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TAB,091900,091900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,092500,092500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,092900,092900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,MRO,093200,093200,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,CPT,093500,093500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,094500,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,CPT,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,MRO,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TAB,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,170100,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,CPT,170400,170400,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,MRO,170700,170700,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,171000,171000,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,171500,171500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TAB,171900,171900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,172500,172500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,172900,172900,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,173500,173500,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,174100,,
```

My code : script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F"," '{print $5}' Data.txt > tmp.txt # print first line first string before , to tmp.txt i.e. all Numbers will be placed into tmp.txt
sort tmp.txt | uniq -d > Uniqe_number.txt # unique values be stored to Uniqe_number.txt
rm tmp.txt # removes tmp file
while read line; do
echo $line
cat Data.txt | grep ",$line," > Numbers/All/$line.txt # grep Number and creats files induvidtually
awk -F"," '{print $5","$4","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11}' Numbers/All/$line.txt > Numbers/All/tmp_$line.txt
mv Numbers/All/tmp_$line.txt Numbers/Final/Final_$line.txt
done < Uniqe_number.txt
ls Numbers/Final > files.txt
dos2unix files.txt
bash time_replace.sh
```

when you execute above script it will call time_replace.sh script

My Code for time_replace.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat files.txt`
do
while read aline
do
TimeDep=`echo $aline | awk -F"," '{print $6}'`
#echo $TimeDep
finalTimeDep=`echo $TimeDep | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i+=2){printf("%s:",substr($0,i,2))}}'|awk '{sub(/:$/,"")};1'`
#echo $finalTimeDep
##########
TimeAri=`echo $aline | awk -F"," '{print $7}'`
#echo $TimeAri
finalTimeAri=`echo $TimeAri | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i+=2){printf("%s:",substr($0,i,2))}}'|awk '{sub(/:$/,"")};1'`
#echo $finalTimeAri
sed -i 's/',$TimeDep'/',$finalTimeDep'/g' Numbers/Final/$i
sed -i 's/',$TimeAri'/',$finalTimeAri'/g' Numbers/Final/$i
############################
done < Numbers/Final/$i
done
```

Any better solution?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: So, you're changing `10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,072200,072200,` into: `10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,07:22:00,07:22:00, `?

Comment: I'm shocked that it only takes 2 hours to run.

Comment: If you have perl available on the box, this is the kind of thing that perl regular expression (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) substitutions are ideal for.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for that but I am not familiar with perl.

Comment: I'd vote for perl also.  I've pushed awk mostly out of my brain, but in awk (gawk), you can read the entire file in at once, set the field separator as `,`, and add in the extra `:` into the 10th and 11th fields.  (I'm not sure if some irregular lines are intentional or are typos.)  The key is that you shouldn't be breaking it up in ksh at all -- do all the work in awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what all your sorting and uniq-ing is for.  I'm assuming your data file has only one entry per line, and you need to change the 10th and 11th comma-separated fields from HHMMSS to HH:MM:SS.

```
while IFS=, read -a line ; do
    echo -n ${line[0]},${line[1]},${line[2]},${line[3]},
    echo -n ${line[4]},${line[5]},${line[6]},${line[7]},
    echo -n ${line[8]},${line[9]},
    if [ -n "${line[10]}" ]; then
        echo -n ${line[10]:0:2}:${line[10]:2:2}:${line[10]:4:2}
    fi
    echo -n ,
    if [ -n "${line[11]}" ]; then
        echo -n ${line[11]:0:2}:${line[11]:2:2}:${line[11]:4:2}
    fi
    echo ""
done < data.txt
```

The operative part is the `${variable:offset:length}` construct that lets you extract substrings out of a variable.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Jonathan and Evil. I am adopting Evil's solution (which is easier for me to understand).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a large quantity of files, then the pipelines are probably what are going to impact performance more than anything else - although processes can be cheap, if you're doing a huge amount of processing then cutting down the amount of time you do pass data through a pipeline can reap dividends.

So you're probably going to be better off writing the entire script in awk (or perl). For example, awk can send output to an arbitary file, so the `while` lop in your first file could be replaced with an awk script that does this. You also don't need to use a temporary file.

I assume the sorting is just for tracking progress easily as you know how many numbers there are. But if you don't care for the sorting, you can simply do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F ',' '
{
    print $5","$4","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11 > Numbers/Final/Final_$line.txt
}' datafile.txt
ls Numbers/Final > files.txt
```

Alternatively, if you need to sort you can do `sort -t, -k5,4,10` (or whichever field your sort keys actually need to be).

As for formatting the datetime, awk also does functions, so you could actually have an awk script that looks like this. This would replace ***both*** of your scripts above whilst retaining the same functionality (at least, as far as I can make out with a quick analysis) ... (Note! Untested, so may contain vauge syntax errors):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
function formattime (t)
{
    return substr(t,1,2)":"substr(t,3,2)":"substr(t,5,2)
}
{
    print $5","$4","$7","$8","$9","formattime($10)","formattime($11) > Numbers/Final/Final_$line.txt
}
```

which you can save, chmod 700, and call directly as:

```
dostuff.awk filename
```

Other awk options include changing fields in-situ, so if you want to maintain the entire original file but with formatted datetimes, you can do a modification of the above. Change the `print` block to:

```
{
    $10=formattime($10)
    $11=formattime($11)
    print $0
}
```

If this doesn't do everything you need it to, hopefully it gives some ideas that will help the code.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, that's close to child's play:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English( -no_match_vars );

local($OFS) = ",";
while (<>)
{
    my(@F) = split /,/;
    $F[9]  =~ s/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/$1:$2:$3/ if defined $F[9];
    $F[10] =~ s/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/$1:$2:$3/ if defined $F[10];
    print @F;
}
```

If you don't want to use `English`, you can write `local($,) = ",";` instead; it controls the output field separator, choosing to use comma.  The code reads each line in the file, splits it up on the commas, takes the last two fields, counting from zero, and (if they're not empty) inserts colons in between the pairs of digits.  I'm sure a 'Code Golf' solution would be made a lot shorter, but this is semi-legible if you know any Perl.

This will be quicker by far than the script, not least because it doesn't have to sort anything, but also because all the processing is done in a single process in a single pass through the file.  Running multiple processes per line of input, as in your code, is a performance disaster when the files are big.

The output on the sample data you gave is:

```
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,07:16:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,07:22:00,07:22:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TAB,07:26:00,07:26:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,07:32:00,07:32:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,07:35:00,07:35:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,MRO,07:37:00,07:37:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,CPT,07:39:00,07:39:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8503,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,07:44:00,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,,09:02:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,09:09:00,09:09:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,09:15:00,09:15:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TAB,09:19:00,09:19:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,09:25:00,09:25:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,09:29:00,09:29:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,MRO,09:32:00,09:32:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,CPT,09:35:00,09:35:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8505,ABCXYZ,D,N,TMP,09:45:00,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,CPT,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,MRO,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TAB,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8506,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,,17:01:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,CPT,17:04:00,17:04:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,MRO,17:07:00,17:07:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:10:00,17:10:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:15:00,17:15:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TAB,17:19:00,17:19:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:25:00,17:25:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:29:00,17:29:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:35:00,17:35:00,
10,SRI,AA,20091210,8510,ABCXYZ,U,N,TMP,17:41:00,,
```